# Searching for a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

Consider the following set of functions:
$$
A=\left\{f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R}): f(0)=0, \lim_{r\searrow 0}\frac{f(r)}{r}\text{ exists}\right\}.
$$

Is there a sequence $(f_n)\in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_n\searrow 0$ but 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{r\searrow 0}\frac{f_n(r)}{r}\neq 0?
$$

Maybe you can give me some hints since I did not find such a sequence yet.

Comment: What do you mean with $f_n\searrow 0$ ? $f_n$ converges pointwise or uniformly to $0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$f_n(t)=\begin{cases}
t,&(0\le t<1/n),
\\ 2/n-t,&(1/n\le t<2/n),
\\0,&(2/n\le t\le 1).
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

$f_n(x) = x (1-x)^n$ is an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing functions which are right differentiable at $0$ consider that $\frac{f(r)}{r}=-\frac{(f(0)-f(r+0))}{r}.$ Thus your limit as $r$ goes to $0$ is the negative of the derivative at $0.$ So any sequence of functions which are differentiable at $0$ but where the derivative does not vanish should do the trick. Such as a sequence of linear functions with slope converging to 1 for example.

Comment: No, f in A means that the right side derivative exists. the derivative need not to exist.

Comment: Yes but in the case of finding a sequence of functions if the derivative exists, then certainly the right side exists :)

Comment: SO...like I suggested $f_n(t)=(1+\frac{1}{n})t$ for example.

Comment: Why  $f_n\searrow 0$?

Comment: @H.Hawks Look at all the answers...

Comment: We can verify that $f_n(0)=(1+1/n)0=0$ and as $t$ goes to $0$ the limit $f_n(t)/t$ becomes the negative of the derivative which is $1+1/n$ which certainly exists. Thus $f_n$ is in $A.$

Comment: But your $f_n$ does not tend to $0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, I overlooked your answer, sorry! I now have a look on it. :D